# Matrix class operators + and * end up with segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, operator-overloading

Basically I have to do a Matrix class implementation. I've done most of it, but I stumbled upon a certain problem, and I really don't know what is actually wrong.

First off, this is my `matrix.hpp` header:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>

class Matrix {

  int columns;
  int rows;
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> vals;
  int matcheck (std::vector<std::vector<int>>);

public:
  Matrix (int, int, std::vector<std::vector<int>>);
  Matrix (int, int);
  ~Matrix();
  const Matrix operator + (const Matrix&) const;
  const Matrix operator * (const Matrix&) const;
  Matrix &operator = (const Matrix&);

  void inverse (Matrix&);
  void setValues (Matrix&, std::vector<std::vector<int>>); 
  void printMatrix ();

  static void changeSize (Matrix&, int, int);
  static void transpose (Matrix&);
};
```

Next, the operator overload implementations:

```
const Matrix Matrix::operator + (const Matrix& mat) const {

    if ( !(rows == mat.rows && columns == mat.columns) ) {

        std::cout << "For addition the matrices must be the same size.\n"; 
        exit(-1); 
    }

    Matrix res (mat.rows, mat.columns);

    for (unsigned int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {

        for (unsigned int col = 0; col < columns; ++col) {

            res.vals[row][col] += this->vals[row][col] + mat.vals[row][col];
        }
    }

    return res;
}

const Matrix Matrix::operator * (const Matrix& mat) const {

    Matrix res (rows, mat.columns);

    if (columns != mat.rows) { 

        std::cout<<"For multiplication the matrix A's columns must be the same number as matrix B's rows\n"; 
        exit(-1);
    }

    for (unsigned int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {

        for (unsigned int col = 0; col < mat.columns; ++col) {

            int sum = 0;

            for (unsigned int k = 0; k < columns; ++k) {

                sum = sum + (vals[row][k] * mat.vals[k][col]);
            }

            res.vals[row][col] = sum;
        }
    }

    return res;
}

Matrix &Matrix::operator = (const Matrix& mat) {

    rows = mat.rows;
    columns = mat.columns;
    vals = mat.vals;

    return *this;
}
```

Now, to illustrate the case in point, in `main()` I did a couple tests, and it looks like this:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "matrix.hpp"

int main() {

    Matrix mat(4, 4, { {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1} });
    Matrix mat2(4, 4, { {2, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 2} });
    Matrix mat5(4, 2, { {1, 12}, {5, 66}, {9, 6}, {7, 19}});

    Matrix mat3 = mat + mat2;
    mat3.printMatrix();

    Matrix mat4 = mat * mat5;
    mat4.printMatrix();

    mat4 = mat2;
    mat4.printMatrix();

    Matrix MAT(4, 4);
    MAT.printMatrix();
    MAT = mat5;

    mat5.printMatrix();
    Matrix::transpose(mat5);
    mat5.printMatrix();

    mat5 = mat;
    mat5.printMatrix();
    mat5 = mat4 + mat2;

    return 0;
}
```

Now, all the operations prior to the last one work pretty well. But as soon as I get to that last one (`mat5 = mat4 + mat2`), I get the segfault. Also, if I use `*` instead, I get still a segfault. Same thing happens if I try to instantiate a Matrix object, or if I use any of my functions, like `transpose()`.

I modified my implementations of the operators, and also googling a bit, they seem to be alright, or at least it seems to me.

This might be just me being dumb, but I really can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Function `transpose()`:

```
void Matrix::transpose (Matrix& mat) {

    Matrix res (mat.rows, mat.columns);
    res = mat;
    changeSize (mat, mat.columns, mat.rows);

    for (unsigned int col = 0; col < res.rows; ++col) {

        for (unsigned int row = 0; row < res.columns; ++row) {

            mat.vals[row][col] = res.vals[col][row];
        }
    }
}
```

And `changeSize()` as well:

```
void Matrix::changeSize (Matrix& mat, int rows, int cols) {

    mat.vals.clear();

    mat.rows = rows;
    mat.columns = cols; 
}
```

EDIT:

I am also sharing the whole `matrix.cpp` source file, so I can give a fully reproducible program. I put a pastebin link since I already have quite a lot of code, and pasting a whole source file here would make the post huge. https://pastebin.com/AmJqhjKT

Comment: The dimension check for addition is wrong – a * b = b * a, but you can't add those unless a = b.

Comment: Please post `transpose`.

Comment: The size test in `operator+` is incorrect. There are lots of combinations of values whose products are the same. The correct test is `rows == mat.rows && columns == mat.columns`.

Comment: Consider making the class a template, with the two dimensions as template arguments. That way adding two matrices that are different sizes will be a compile-time error.

Comment: Indentation please

Comment: Ok, I added transpose and changeSize (which is used in transpose). Also, fixed the check for addition.

Answer (score 1):

`changeSize` updates the `rows` and `columns` members, but leaves the vector empty.  Any reference to it afterwards will be Undefined Behavior.

`changeSize` and `transpose` can/should be non-static member functions, since you're passing a matrix as the first parameter and returning the result in that same object.

Comment: Indeed, I overlooked the vector filling. Still, can't really figure why it just segfaults whatever I put after that last `mat5.printMatrix()`, except for the overloaded operator `=`. Also, why just there, I use the operators `+` and `*` right at the beginning and they work, but for some reason, in that last line it just will give me the segfault.

Comment: @CatalinC Accessing a vector out of bounds is Undefined Behavior. As far as the C++ language is concerned, literally anything can happen, including demons flying out of your nose, but also including your code appearing to work some of the time.

Comment: @alterigel Oh, I wasn't saying I don't know why it doesn't work because of the vector. What I meant was, I fixed the problem with the vector, but I still get the segfault, so that is why I'm perplexed.

Comment: Have you tried running your code through a debugger? If not, there's a great read here: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @CatalinC Since your code is not compilable (because it is missing the `Matrix` constructors) we can only guess. [Edit] the question to include a [mre].